# Impact of Altering an Oracle sequence from ORDER to NO ORDER

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have a table `TAX_INFO` where the primary key `TAX_INFO_ID` is generated using a sequence `SEQ_TAX_INFO_ID`.

Below is the sequence definition, It is ORDERED at the moment

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  SEQ_TAX_INFO_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 10000 CACHE 5000 ORDER  NOCYCLE
```

Currently this TAX_INFO_ID is used in many queries involving **order by** , **MAX**,  **MIN** clauses.

As we have moved to RAC architecture recently, there's a requirement to alter the sequence to `NO ORDER` so that the sequence usage can be improved.

Will there be any impact on the existing queries that uses the TAX_INFO_ID in **order by** , **MAX**,  **MIN** clauses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can/will be impact because [NOORDER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) doesn't guarantee order

Therefore you should use different column of date/timestamp type  (insert/update/end time) for guaranteed order by or min/max function.

> **NOORDER** 
>   Specify NOORDER if you do not want to guarantee sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This is the default.